# objective-c iphone programming : try catch exceptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, try-catch, nsrange

im using kumulos to have access to a database.
this is the code i am talking about :

```
NSString *location = [[theResults objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"location"];
```

Now the thing if [theResults objectatindex:0] return "null" it crash everytime
so if the user enter something that is not in the database it crash i want to catch this exeption (NSRange exeception).

Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't crash if [theResults objectAtIndex:0] is nil. All that should happen is that location becomes nil itself. Objective-C allows every [nil whatever] method call and all of them return nil, so double-check that this is actually the case? I bet you it isn't, but feel free to surprise me :)

Comment: yep. location becomes nil, then he tries to use location, i guess, in some code that ends up trying to dereference the pointer :)

Comment: It's also possible that the NSRangeException is happening because [theResults count] == 0.

Comment: You do *not* want to catch the range exception.  Either figure out why the your array is empty *or* check to make sure it isn't empty first (as suggested by GregInYEG).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work for you without requiring exception handling.

```
if ([theResults count] > 0) {
    NSString *location = [[theResults objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"location"];
}
```

I'm assuming that `theResults` is an `NSArray` (or subclass).

Comment: As commented above, [nil foo] doesn't crash, it returns nil, so your suggestion shouldn't be necessary. The question is why his code is crashing in the first place. I presume it's later on when he's using location in a must-not-be-nil situation, but I could be wrong.

Comment: if (row!=nil) check is not necessary, moreover - if row is nil then your location variable (which is likely to be used afterwards) will contain garbage. So you need to init it with nil or just write NSString* location = [row objectForKey:@"location"]; without redundant checks

Comment: I think you were both looking at a previous edit of my answer. I removed the unnecessary row != nil check already. I think the code is crashing because he's dealing with an empty theResults array.

Comment: Ah, of course. If the array is empty he'll get a range exception (and that's what he's getting, too .. d'oh, my bad).

Answer (score 1):

either you check that [theResults objectAtIndex:0] does not return nil, or you use exception handling

```
@try {
   NSString *location = [[theResults objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"location"];  
}
@catch (NSRangeEception * e) {
   NSLog(@"catching %@ reason %@", [e name], [e reason]);
}
@finally {
   //something that you want to do wether the exception is thrown or not.
}
```

I would suggest to study the language at least a little bit, though, or practice with google :-)

Comment: You do *not* use exception handling in iOS to catch-handle-and-continue.  An exception thrown by the frameworks is indicative of an unrecoverable error generally caused by a bug your code.  For arrays, if there is a question of content, you use the `count` method to check presence of an object at index and **never** use exception handling for that.

Comment: This is definitely not the way to go. All he has to do is check if [theResults count] is or is not 0.

Comment: 1. the question was: "how do I catch the NSRangeException"? and the answer is with @try @catch, or what
2. if you use objectAtIndex with an index out of bound an NSRangeException exception is thrown without having some catastrophic bug in the code. You should use count, true, but I don't see that big error in the @catch. 3. given these premises, i think that two downcast are not justified, but who cares.

Comment: I'd also like to add that if you really have a point against exception usage, you should explain it: saying "nonono that's definitely wrong" without explaining serves no one.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you garph0. I even tried undoing my down-vote but it's locked in place unless you edit your answer. The reason I did down-vote in the first place was because the user was asking for a solution to a crash, and *presuming* they needed exceptions, but I doubt anyone who knew what they were doing would use exceptions in this case. Exceptions are for things you CANNOT predict beforehand. An empty array is not one of those cases.